# Cutting a colour-critical indecomposable graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an arbitrary indecomposable k-colour-critical graph ($k\geq4$). Is it in general possible to find a cut $C=(S,T)$, such that $S$ is a $k-1$-chromatic graph and $T$ is the complete Graph of Order $2$? Or are there any "obvious" counterexamples i have overlooked?